# Stop Meteor http from slowing down page requests

Tags: meteor

I'm quite new to Meteor and relatively new to JS as well.

The code i'm using is:

**server/methods.es6**

```
var cheerio = Meteor.npmRequire('cheerio');

/*****************************************************************************/
/* Server Only Methods */
/*****************************************************************************/
Meteor.methods({
  /*
   * Example:
   *
   * '/app/items/insert': function (item) {
   * }
   */
  player: function () {
    const url = 'http://cdn.content.easports.com/fifa/fltOnlineAssets/C74DDF38-0B11-49b0-B199-2E2A11D1CC13/2014/fut/items/web/165434.json';

    const response = Meteor.http.get(url);

    return response;
  }
});
```

**client/templates/cars/cars_list.es6**

```
Meteor.call('player', function (err, res) {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  console.log(JSON.parse(res.content));

  Session.set('player', JSON.parse(res.content));
});

/*****************************************************************************/
/* CarsList: Event Handlers */
/*****************************************************************************/
Template.CarsList.events({
});

/*****************************************************************************/
/* CarsList: Helpers */
/*****************************************************************************/
Template.CarsList.helpers({
  cars: function () {
    return Cars.find();
  },
  player: function () {
    return Session.get('player');
  }
});
```

**client/templates/cars/cars_list.html**

```
<template name="CarsList">
  <h1>Cars List</h1>

  {{ player.Item.FirstName }}

  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Fuel Type</th>
        <th>Body Style</th>
        <th>Top Speed</th>
        <th>Power</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      {{# each cars }}
        {{> car }}
      {{/ each }}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

Most of it is just test code to try and do HTTP requests.

When i remove all the code related to `player` everything is instant. When the `player` code is there the page loads instantly but the `cars` data doesn't show until the HTTP request for `player` is resolved. Is there a way to put the HTTP request in the background while everything else does what it used to do?

Also is there a way to loop HTTP requests and show the data as i receive it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to put you method code in your `both` folder. That way, latency compensation won't be affected and your user interface will update as fast as it is supposed to.

If you need to hide some of the code from the client, you can put it in both `client` and `server` folders. I have not tested this, but I assume that if the result of the client call is different (i.e. he messed it up with the console) you will rollback its data to the server one.

This way, you simulate the method results from the server while it has not come back yet. However, keep in mind that whatever setup you use, you end up having to wait for the website data to go on, whether it is on client or server. 
If you call your data like that, I think it does not only stop your mongo data, but also your js functions execution (the event loop). I might be wrong (newbie here too)

Maybe you should read about [fiber and future, and the async calls](http://phucnguyen.info/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-async-meteor/). It seems to me it is the way to go.

Good luck!

Comment: What i was aiming to do is scrape a website for some data then it would spit it out on the client as it get's it, but doing this seems to block my Mongo data from pulling through until all requests are resolved

Comment: Awesome thanks, this is definitely a step in the right direction for me. The load is alot quicker so will mark it as accepted :)